# Is this Patricia tree implementation wrong?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, radix-tree, patricia-trie

I'm reading the [chapter](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr09/cos226/handouts/Algs3Ch15.pdf) Radix Search of the book Algorithms (Robert Sedgwick).

I've made a simple implementation and something isn't behaving as expected.

In program `15.5` you can see that we start with an empty tree where the head is a null node. In figure `15.12` you can see that the null node is always the leftmost node. This is also described in the text:

> We use the convention that the leftmost link (the one correspond- ing to a key that is all 0 bits) does not point to any internal node

program `15.7` is the implementation of Patricia-trie insertion.

If you look at the code, there's never a chance for the head reference to change, let's say, to `A` as depicted in figure `15.12`.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

which edition you read,i have this book(algorithms in c,also writtend by sedgewick).i had discoverd the same error code as you said.
first:if the trie is empty ,we first insert a item(sure creat a new node,we named it x),we should make the node be the head of the trie.but the code in the boke don't reflect this.
second:if the trie is not empty,when we insert a node(named x) ,firstly we will find a node which has most sane bit with x,determine i(while (bit(v, i) == bit(w, i)) i++;)  .if x's fist different bit whith head is 0,case1:head.l = insertR(head.l, x, i, head),otherwise case 2:head.r = insertR(head.r, x, i, head);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).